# Regex capture required and optional characters in any position only

Tags: regex

I would like to match against a word only a set of characters in any order but one of those letters is required.

Example:

- Optional letters: `yujkfec`
- Required letter: `d`

Matches: `duck dey feed yudekk dude jude dedededy jejeyyyjd`
No matches (do not contain required): `yuck feck`
No matches (contain letters outside of set): `sucked shock blah food bard`

I've tried `^[d]+[yujkfec]*$` but this only matches when the required letter is in the front. I've tried positive lookaheads but this didn't do much.

Comment: Please avoid answering the question in the comments section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\b[yujkfec]*d[dyujkfec]*\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G1CEzR/1). Note that the `d` is included into the second character class.

*Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `[yujkfec]*` - zero or more occurrences of `y`, `u`, `j`, `k`, `f`, `e` or `c`
- `d` - a `d` char
- `[dyujkfec]*` - zero or more occurrences of `y`, `u`, `j`, `k`, `f`, `e`, `c` or `d`.
- `\b` - a word boundary.